# JQuery mobile collapsible content not appearing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm having some trouble with the JQuery Mobile collapsible content (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-rc.2/docs/content/content-collapsible.html)

This HTML:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Address</h3>
<div id="address_container">
Some hidden content here
</div>  
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>About Us</h3>
<div id="descriptions_container">
Some more hidden content here
</div>
</div>
```

Should be appearing like so:

[image]

Is looking like this:

[image]

In the broken example the buttons do not expand to show the hidden content. The html on the page is as in the example on the jquery mobile site. When the page loads it is initially fine, however in a moment the page flashes, and then displays incorrectly as above. What's worse is that it's not consistent. Sometimes it works and others it doesn't.

The HTML on the broken version shows that it's inserting an entire hidden content container inside the div that contains the hidden content. Here it is after load:

[image]

Any advice or ideas about what causes this and how it can be addressed would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Well I've stopped it happening. I had some debug text being Response.Written to the page outside of the HTML elements at the very beginning of the page and stopping this seems to have stopped the above issue occurring. I suppose JQuery Mobile must be throwing its toys out of the pram in an unusual way because of it.

Comment: Do you `.hide()` / `.show()` it? If you're using JS code, please post it.

Comment: If it works initially, then some JS is modifying it. Please post the javascript code

Answer (score 0):

As the example on jquerymobile.com shows, try using paragraph instead of div for the content. Your code would be

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Address</h3>
<p id="address_container">
Some hidden content here
</p>  
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>About Us</h3>
<p id="descriptions_container">
Some more hidden content here
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it doesn't rectify the problem. It behaves the same as with a div tag.

Comment: Android Decoded is correct. I took the sample Wardrox put together, used the same version of JQM you referenced, and put together a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/UnZXD/ so you could see it in action.

With no other JavaScript running, it works as expected. Something else in the app is modifying the results on you.

Comment: I thought as much also but the only script on the page is the tags for JQuery.

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>